# Flex 3 not getting answers

Tags: apache-flex

Why am I not getting answers for Flex project anymore. Has the developer community from Flex shrinked? I have the feeling that these are very basic questions and that there should be someone out there with an answer I even used this bounty thing but did not seam to get the proper attention.

Comment: I was on working a long time with Flex about 3-2 years ago. But it turned out with all the mobile browsers, that HTML5 with JS is easier, and for me, it's more interesting

Comment: I must plead guilty: if a question is flagged Flex 3, I don't even read it anymore. It has just been too long ago; Flex 4 has been around for at least 5 years now (which is an eternity in web terms).

Answer (score 1):

apache have taken it over from Adobe if that's what you mean ? Website is http://flex.apache.org/about-whatis.html#

Comment: I haven't known that! Maybe, when it's open source, it could get another push ;)

Comment: Haha, Maybe we should be the ones to push it ;)

Comment: Adobe didn't donate the Flex 3 SDK to Apache so you might not get many answer there either.